# Problem with creating a connection to the database

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to dealing with databases and recently I was trying to establish a database connection on the local host using JavaFX using the following code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.Map;

 import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    HBox hBox = new HBox() ;

    Scene scene = new Scene(hBox) ;

    stage.setScene(scene) ;
    stage.show() ;

    Label label = new Label("here the text") ;
    label.setWrapText(true);

    Button button = new Button("button1") ;
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        try{
          Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") ;

          Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","root") ;

          Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;

          ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT text1 FROM table1") ;

          while (resultSet.next()){
              label.setText(label.getText()+"\n"+resultSet.getString("text1")) ;
          }

          connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            label.setText(e.getMessage()+" (Error message!)") ;
        }
    });

    hBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView,button,label) ;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

In addition to that I used MySQL Connector, I tried this code on different environments such as IntelJ and NetBeans, and it works, however, my problem is not with JavaFX,I just wanted to say that I use the same connector,My problem is with Android Studio, when I installed the MySQL connector, I used the following codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com    /apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="241dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="333dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:onClick="Button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and MainActitvity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void Button(View view){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") ;
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","root") ;
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT message1 FROM table1") ;
        while(resultSet.next()){
            String string = resultSet.getString("message1") ;
            textView.setText(string);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        textView.setText("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

When I run the code on a real machine, the Exception e gives me the message "Cannot create a connection to the database server",Whereas when I run the code on a virtual machine the debuger gives me the following error:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mysql.mysql, PID: 3149
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at      androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.j  ava:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method group(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Ljava/util/regex/Matcher; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.regex.Matcher' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.isConnectionStringSupported(ConnectionUrlParser.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:317)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:185)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
    at com.mysql.mysql.MainActivity.Button(MainActivity.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And I am using the latest version and I am sure that the database does not contain an error, so where is the problem?

Comment: What is "localhost" going to point to on a device? I think you need to use a better hostname or I.P. on the network for your DB connection.

Comment: @SamOrozco localhost works with javaFX,so I thinked may its work in android too

Comment: Yeah javafx is running on your desktop, which I presume the database is also running on that's why localhost works. The device is not on your computer where localhost will work.